# How to clear viewer state programmatically like pressing Escape key?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I press Escape key, the viewer state is reset. I would like to achieve the reset function by button on screen. How can you do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can fire the command with below.

viewer.showAll()